# javascript function to accept only 4 digit number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html form with a javascript script defined default value. I am trying to add another javascript that would deny the form being submitted if its empty and on its default value but I cant get to work to deny the form being submitted if the input is characters or non-numeric.

This is the javascript

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
  if ($.trim($('#store').val()) === "" || $.trim($('#store').val()) === "Enter store number'(nnnn)'" || $.trim($('#store').val()) === isNaN(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Please type in store number');
  }
});
```

Comment: Why would you have Enter store number ('9999') why not just a text input that only shows digits and a range. you probably learned jQuery first right it would explain a lot

Comment: `<input pattern='^\s{4}$' >` or `<input type=number min=1000 max=9999>`

Comment: @dandavis the first one will only match four spaces the second one might be right, but only if `0000` to `0999` are not valid (that's something that is not clear in the question)

Comment: @BornKillaz this will allow `8e50`  to be entered.

Comment: @t.niese You were right. Here is my updated version, using regular expressions https://jsfiddle.net/rss5wktb/3/ Thank you for pointed it out.

Comment: @BornKillaz the updated version using regular expression worked. thank you very much

Comment: @t.niese: should be `<input pattern='^\d{4}$' >`, sorry for the typo...

Answer (score 0):

try this on form tag `<form onSubmit="return validation()">`

```
$('document').ready(function(){
function validate(){
        if ($.trim($('#store').val()) === "" || $.trim($('#store').val()) === "Enter store number'(nnnn)'" || $.trim($('#store').val()) === isNaN(e) ) {

   alert('Please type in store number');
return false;
        }
else{
return true;
}

}
});
```

return false to prevent from submitting form